# Map string (key) to number (or any data)

Tags: go, switch-statement, mapping

In JavaScript I can do something like this:

```js
const periods = {
  'mercury': 0.2408467,
  'venus': 0.61519726,
  'earth': 1.0,
  'mars': 1.8808158,
  'jupiter': 11.862615,
  'saturn': 29.447498,
  'uranus': 84.016846,
  'neptune': 164.79132,
};

const planetName = prompt();
const period = periods[planetName];
```

How can I do similar thing in go-lang?

Comment: See map literals in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19).  Use this statement: `periods := map[string]float64{
  "mercury": 0.2408467,
  "venus":   0.61519726,
  "earth":   1.0,
  "mars":    1.8808158,
  "jupiter": 11.862615,
  "saturn":  29.447498,
  "uranus":  84.016846,
  "neptune": 164.79132,
 }`

Comment: Thank you, it looks much better than my approach:
```go
  periods := make(map[string]float64)
  periods["mercury"] = 0.2408467
  periods["venus"] = 0.61519726
  periods["earth"] = 1.0
  periods["mars"] = 1.8808158
  periods["jupiter"] = 11.862615
  periods["saturn"] = 29.447498
  periods["uranus"] = 84.016846
  periods["neptune"] = 164.79132
```

Answer (score 2):

You came very close to answering your own question. :)

Just put those tags on google.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    periods := map[string]float32{
        "mercury": 0.2408467,
        "venus":   0.61519726,
    }

    fmt.Println(periods["mercury"])
}
```